# Best way to generate a consecutive id in Python

Tags: python

Given a class that has an attribute `self.id` I need to populate that attribute with a counter starting at 0 and all objects of that class need a unique id during a single run of the program. What is the best/ most pythonic way of doing this? Currently I use

```
def _get_id():
    id_ = 0
    while True:
       yield id_
       id_ += 1
get_id = _get_id()
```

which is defined outside the class and

```
self.id = get_id.next()
```

in the class' `__init__()`. Is there a better way to do this? Can the generator be included in the class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [itertools.count](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count

class MyClass(object):
    id_counter = count().next
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = self.id_counter()
```

Comment: Why not `id_counter = count()` and `self.id = id_counter.next()`?

Comment: @cdhowie: the documentation doesn't say anything about it, so I wouldn't count on it. If you're worried about thread safety you can protect the ID assignment with a `threading.Lock`. (_EDIT_: actually [this page](http://29a.ch/2009/2/20/atomic-get-and-increment-in-python) suggests that `counter.next()` is atomic, although that would probably be implementation-dependent)

Comment: @joaquin - just because there is no reason to do the extra attribute access every time.

Answer (score 4):

Why use iterators / generators at all? They do the job, but isn't it overkill? Whats wrong with

```
class MyClass(object):
  id_ctr = 0
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = MyClass.id_ctr
    MyClass.id_ctr += 1
```

Comment: Because this is what `count` is for. Yes, it's simple to reimplement, but then you can forget to increment the counter in a subclass that overrides `__init__`. You can't forget to increment the counter if it's done automatically.

Comment: good point regarding overriding __init__, but doesn't the solution with count() still require the subclasser to 'magically know' they should call self.id_counter() -  either that or as I would normally expect, calling Myclass.__init__(self) in the overriding __init__ is a sensible thing to do?

Comment: Yep, no way to remove the need to do it right, it's just one less thing to possibly get wrong.

Comment: One thing to do per subclass is better than two things to do per subclass. The `count` approach is more neatly factored.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated answer for Python 3

Use [itertools.count](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```py
from itertools import count

id_counter = count(start=1)
def get_id():
    return next(id_counter)

first_id  = get_id() # --> 1
second_id = get_id() # --> 2
```